# Edit Chinese text in a UITextView

Tags: ios, keyboard, uitextview

I have an App for the iPhone with a UITextView that I use to enter and edit text. I plan to also target my app for the Chinese market, so I added some Chinese keyboards in Settings so I could test it. So now I have in total 10 keyboards (Eng, Swe and 8 Chinese ones). Once I try to enter text into the UITextView I can only change between the English and Swedish keyboard, not any of the Chinese ones.

If I do the same thing for a UILabel I can change between all keyboards and enter Chinese text (even if I don't understand what I write ;-)

Have anyone experienced this and have a solution for it? I have not found any documentation from Apple regarding this…

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either in Interface Builder or your code where you deal with your text field, you need to change the UIKeyboardType

```
UITextField *field = [[UITextField alloc] init];
field.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeDefault;
```

I'm guessing you probably have it currently set to UIKeyboardTypeASCIICapable, which only let me to to English and Swedish (I also have Japanese and Chinese included).

Reference for the keyboard types: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UITextInputTraits_Protocol/Reference/UITextInputTraits.html